# How to show the Finished button in the quiz instead of Next button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The web application that I am developing right now has something called quiz engine which provides users with short quizzes which consist of one question or more. Now, I have a problem with the QUIZ page. The quiz may consist of one question or more. The main problem that I have is following: If the quiz consists of one question, when the user comes to this quiz, he will see the NEXT button instead of seeing the FINISHED button. However, if the quiz consists of more than one question, he will see the FINISHED button in the page with the last question. I don't know why this is happening with me. Any help please?

For creating the Quiz engine, I used  [the Toturial in the ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/building-20-applications/lesson-11-building-a-quiz-engine-1)   for creating it.

My ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="resultGrid" runat="server" DataKeyNames="QuestionID" SelectedIndex="0" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="resultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="555px">
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="generaltext" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionID" HeaderText="Question" />
                            <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="CorrectAnswer" HeaderText="Correct Answer" />--%>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserAnswer" HeaderText="Your Answer" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Result" HeaderText="Result" />
                        </Columns>
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" CssClass="boldtext" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [Question], [Answer1], [Answer2], [Answer3], [QuestionID], [QuestionOrder], [Answer4], [CorrectAnswer], [AnswerExplanation], [QuizID] FROM [Question] WHERE ([QuizID] = @QuizID) ORDER BY [QuestionOrder]">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:SessionParameter Name="QuizID" SessionField="QuizID" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>  

<asp:DetailsView ID="answerDetails" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
                        GridLines="None" Height="45px" Width="552px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="QuestionID">

                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="generaltext" />
                        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="boldtext" Width="100px" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Question" 
                                SortExpression="Question" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer1" HeaderText="A" 
                                SortExpression="Answer1" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer2" HeaderText="B" 
                                SortExpression="Answer2" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer3" HeaderText="C" 
                                SortExpression="Answer3" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer4" HeaderText="D" 
                                SortExpression="Answer4" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CorrectAnswer" HeaderText="Correct Answer" 
                                SortExpression="CorrectAnswer" HeaderStyle-BackColor="lightgreen" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="AnswerExplanation" HeaderText="Explanation" 
                                SortExpression="AnswerExplanation" HeaderStyle-BackColor="lightgreen" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DetailsView>
```

My code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        questionDetails.DataBind();
    }

    protected void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save off previous answers
        System.Data.DataRowView dr = (System.Data.DataRowView)questionDetails.DataItem;

        // Create Answer object to save values
        Answer a = new Answer();
        a.QuestionID = dr["QuestionOrder"].ToString();
        a.CorrectAnswer = dr["CorrectAnswer"].ToString();
        a.UserAnswer = answerDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();

        ArrayList al = (ArrayList)Session["AnswerList"];
        al.Add(a);

        Session.Add("AnswerList", al);

        if (questionDetails.PageIndex == questionDetails.PageCount - 1)
        {
            // Go to evaluate answers
            Response.Redirect("Results.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            questionDetails.PageIndex++;
        }

        if (questionDetails.PageIndex == questionDetails.PageCount - 1)
        {
            nextButton.Text = "Finished";
        }

    }
```

**SO HOW TO FIX THIS PROBLEM?**

Comment: Why the down-votes? Seems like a reasonably phrased question to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the button text to "Finished" until the nextButton_Click event is fired. Presumably it's labelled "Next" by default.

Try this in your Page_Load, or elsewhere before the button click:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{     
    questionDetails.DataBind();  

    if (questionDetails.PageCount == 1)       
    {       
        nextButton.Text = "Finished";       
    }   
}
```

This assumes a PageCount of 1 means there's 1 question.